# How to create a separate activity for each eBook?

Tags: java, android, gridview, cardview

I practiced with below source code. But I want to create separate activities for separate books.I can add more books to this app.But I can't create separate activities for each and every books.It means anyone click any book should open it's activity(let's think open pdf version view of the book).Please help me to create it.I want full code.because I'm a bigginer...Thank you...You can edit it via Github.....

https://github.com/MrMarkSteven/Book_Menu

[see images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7COM.jpg)

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BookDetailActivity` like the one that you have created in your source code.

Then you have to implement `Serializable` in your POJO class. ie. `Book.java` Just write `public class Book implements Serializable` and then you will be able to pass a single `Book` object from your `RecyclerViewAdapter` to `BookDetailActivity` via an `Intent`.

You can do so by using following code in your `holder.cardView.setOnClickListener`'s `onClick`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BookDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Book", mData.get(position)); //mData is a list of books and mData.get(position) will give a Book object.
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

And in you `BookDetailActivity` use the following code to get the object from the intent.

```
// To retrieve object in second Activity
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("Book")){
       Book book= (Book) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Book");
        Log.d(TAG, " Got serialized object "+ book.getTitle());
/*
Then you can get what you want from the Book object and set to textviews          or other stuffs.
*/
    }
```

I have assumed that your `holder.cardView.setOnClickListener` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the RecyclerViewAdapter.java on click method of cardView.

```
 holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(mData.get(position).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("The Vegitarian")){

                   // move to another activity
                 }

                 else if(mData.get(position).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("The Wild Robot")){
                       // move to another activity
                 }

                 // continue ..

        }
    });
```

Comment: It is right but this is not a proper way , here you have know the details of book but you cant always get the details that you want to show

Comment: This way, one will have to create a thousand `else if`s if there are thousand books. And not to mention thousand Activities. Don't you think?

Comment: I know this , what are you trying to say but the question asked "I want to create separate activities for separate books". so he wants different activity.

Comment: Yeah,I want different  activities.It means different pdf for different books via assets folder...

Comment: Just compare getIntent() in next activity not create multiple activity.

Comment: There is no need to create multiple activity just compare your getIntent value and open your assets according to them.